# Angular 6 headers with post request does't work

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, cors

I'm using Angular 6 for my front-end and a Web API based on Core2 for my server. I wrote this code and this worked when I used ASP.NET client side, but with Angular I have some troubles.

[image]

```
services.AddMvc():
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("FreePolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.WithHeaders(<redacted>)
    //builder.AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyOrigin();
}));
```

If I comment `builder.WithHeaders` and uncomment `builder.AllowAnyHeader` the errors go away, but otherwise Angular crashes.

My headers:

[image]

This looks like the place with my error because "MaybeUnknown". You can see brackets around the value, so this looks like an array. Can I fix it and will it solve my problem?

I'm getting errors after my post request on a server if I don't uncomment `builder.AllowAnyHeader`.

[image]

**UPDATE**

My headers on server side

[image]

MY headers on client
[image]

**UPDATE 2**
Configure method
[image]

**UPDATE 3**
[image]

Comment: According to your description, I guess you're sending the request with a custom header, but you don't have the header configured on server side at the same time.Check the ajax on client side and the headers on server side. If you still can't solve the problem, show us the line `WithHeaders(<redacted>)` and the ajax part of code in Angular to let us know what will be sent to the server.

Comment: @itminus I updated post, please check this. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear from the latest screenshot you've posted, which shows the HTTP request that's being made through Chrome, that you have a missing header in your `WithHeaders` call. If you look at `Access-Control-Request-Headers` in the request, you'll see it contains *four* headers:

- apiss
- client-id
- zump-api-version
- **content-type**

However, your `WithHeaders` call does *not* include `Content-Type`, so you'll need to add that:

```
builder.WithHeaders("client-id", "zump-api-version", "apiss", "content-type")
    ...
```

Note: This is all case-insensitive, so you can case it in whichever way you'd prefer.

There's more information about this in the MDN docs: [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), which includes the following explanation:

> Note that certain headers are always allowed: Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type (but only with a MIME type of its parsed value (ignoring parameters) of either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain). These are called the simple headers, and you don't need to specify them explicitly.

This explains why you don't have to specify `Accept` (it's a "simple header"). You *do* have to specify `Content-Type` in your example because it is neither of the three MIME types referenced in the statement above.